# Android Gradle exception error could not list content of directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I run the project I get gradle exception error, could not list content of directory.... Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem? Thanks!

I am sharing the error, this is all I am getting. I hope this helps. [image: gradle build error]

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help us answer your question you should 1) Give us the actual error. 2) give us your build.gradle file that is causing the errors. (Feel free to edit it if you need to keep some personal data private, but try to keep that to a minimum) Without both of these, it will be very difficult for anyone to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. The Android Gradle could not reach the directory because it was somehow corrupted. I have switched to Windows 10 last month and apparently folders get corrupted for some unknown reason. So when I carried out disk scanning plus repairing the problem was solved. Thought I should share if anyone else runs into this Gradle exception error: Could not reach content of directory...